# how to horizontally align label and select tags in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem is that there is a big gap between the `labels` and `select tags`

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
  <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 contro-label ">What Skill will you be working on?</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option>PHP</option>
                  <option>JAVA</option>

              </select>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 contro-label">What Course?</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option>CMP</option>

                  <option>IT</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 contro-label">Section?</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
              <select class="form-control input-sm">
                  <option>Select</option>

                  <option>34432</option>
                  <option>44333</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</fieldset>  
</form>
```

I tried to add some `col-sm-x` inside my `row` but didn't work.  Here is an image on how it looks like:
[image: Form]

I also tried to add the `pull-right` class inside my labels, but since `label` and `select tag` are inside the same `form-group` I think this is causing the all thing to move out of place

Comment: You have an issue with the number of columns. Check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Comment: try again. You probably tried when I was editing the comment.

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand what you want. You want the labels flushed to the right, not the left, correct?

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt yes.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a **L** :
`<label class="col-sm-4 contro-label">` to `<label class="col-sm-4 control-label">`

And it'll magically align right ;)

take a look at [Bootstrap #forms-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: That was a really good catch! that is the problem of copy and paste sometimes, especially,  when you have a mistake!

Comment: For the record, the Bootstrap CSS documentation doesn't actually identify that control-label is meant to align text. Just FYI.

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt yes, the BS doc is not really technical on this kind of things, the best way is the browser inspection with the uncompressed CSS

Comment: @Blag My concern that led to mentioning it is that we have no way to actually confirm that it is how the developers wanted it to actually be, and that it could change without any notice because it was overlooked in the documentation. It's still very useful, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

With `.form-horizontal`, every `.control-label` child **will** be right-aligned for `sm` and more.

So, correcting the `.control-label` should be sufficient.

However, since there is no designation of how the smaller resolutions should be rendered, you can add `.text-right` to maintain the right alignment regardless of the resolution.

Here's a Bootply to make it easier to see: http://www.bootply.com/LtdAfSi0B3

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text-right">What Skill will you be working on?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>PHP</option>
                <option>JAVA</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text-right">What Course?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>CMP</option>
                <option>IT</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label text-right">Section?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option>34432</option>
                <option>44333</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Source**: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Comment: yesssssssssssssssssssssssssssss..so the `text-right` did the magic?

Comment: **don't use this, it's wrong** check my answer, you forgot a **L** on your `contro-label` class, that's why it's not auto right align

Comment: @AMaduro Yes...and no. Correcting the `.control-label` should've resolved it, also. Add `.text-right` is more like a "just-in-case".

Comment: @Blag My answer covers both. I reworded to make that a little clearer. My apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt you don't need `text-right` : it's against the responsive display (on `xs` it'll still be right align, even if the field is show under) ; the correction on the magic-label `control-label` is the good way ;)

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt I see that the `text-right` was right but when I add the `l` at the end of the `control-label` and delete the `text-right` the `labels` move to a better position `to the perfect position`

Comment: @AMaduro That's why I said **AND/OR**. Your original post gives no information on your intended view at the lower resolutions.

Comment: @Blag I agree, but there was no identification of how A Maduro wanted it to appear at the lower resolutions. As such, I included it as an **AND/OR** scenario. If you consider it poor for my given a broader answer due to lack of specification by the asker, please, downvote my answer, give your reasoning, and we can leave it at that.

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt it's not against you, it's just a warning for beginner that can copy/past without understanding, with form control *you shouldn't* need that trick

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt I know what you mean, and your answer is totally right, but, your answer didn't fix the `L`..not sure if you edit after @Blag mentioned it...I know it because when you posted your answer I copied it and pasted it and it worked but, then I look at the comment from @Blag and saw that the 'L' was missing in your answer too. So, that's why I think that @Blag fixed the issue.

Comment: @ChristopherEsbrandt and I really appreciate that you took your time to get the `css` links and copy the code to test it.

Comment: @AMaduro You are correct, the original post did not fix it because I overlooked it, myself. I had, honestly, noticed before I saw that Blag had made a post. I think we can just chalk the whole confusion up to bad timing. ^^'

Comment: @Blag I understand and apologize. I misunderstood the tone of your replies. ^^'

Comment: @Blag Thanks for taking the time to recommend an editing of my answer. I tweaked it a little, but it's greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the `col-sm-4` class for your labels, you are forcing them to take up one third of their container. Try reducing this to `col-sm-3` or `col-sm-2`.

Remember to see how your form looks at different browser sizes. You may want to specify some `col-xs-*`, `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*` classes as well to ensure that the form is displayed as you want in different browser sizes. See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more details.

Comment: not a good idea.  If i do that the I might fix the first label but not the short labels such as `course` and `section` =/ I tested it.

Comment: How do you want the form to look? If you want the selects to line up vertically then you'll inevitably end up with a large gap to the right of the shorter labels. Or aren't you worried about the selects lining up vertically?

Comment: Vertically? I haven't mention vertically.  I am trying to line up horizontally, to make them looks nice

Comment: What I meant was, at the moment your selects looks nice in that they are lined up vertically. If you allowed only a small gap between each left-aligned label and its select then they would no longer be vertically aligned and would look (I think) worse. Alternatively, you could right-align the labels by adding the `text-right` class to your labels.